ControlOptions Type Assertion Required for FormArray but Breaks FormControl
I'm facing an interesting discrepancy between passing AbstractControlOptions to FormControl vs FormArray.
I have my own classes for my form control objects and I have a custom type in order to keep the everything strongly typed.
type StageControlType = {
  stageVolume: FormControl<number>;
  actions: FormArray<ActionControl>;
};


export class StageControl extends FormGroup<StageControlType> {
  constructor() {
    super({
      stageVolume: new FormControl(DEFAULT_STAGE_VALUES.stageVolume),
      actions: new FormArray<ActionControl>(
        [].actions.map(() => new ActionControl()),
      ),
    });
  }
}

This gives me an expected error:
error TS2322: Type 'FormControl<number | null>' is not assignable to type 'FormControl<number>'.
  Type 'number | null' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'.

          stageVolume: new FormControl(DEFAULT_STAGE_VALUES.stageVolume),

To fix this, I add the non-nullable option to the stageVolume attribute:
stageVolume: new FormControl(DEFAULT_STAGE_VALUES.stageVolume{
  nonNullable: true, 
})

This fixes the error. At this point, I wonder why I'm getting the error with my FormControl property but not my FormArray property. So just to be safe, I add non-nullable to my FormArray property too:
actions: new FormArray<ActionControl>(
  DEFAULT_STAGE_VALUES.actions.map(() => new ActionControl()),
  {nonNullable: true}, 
),

And that change gives me this error
error TS2353: Object literal may only specify known properties, 
and 'nonNullable' does not exist in type 
'AbstractControlOptions | ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[]'.

            {nonNullable: true},
             ~~~~~~~~~~~

That error does not make any sense to me, because FormControl and FormArray both extend AbstractControl and accept AbstractControlOptions as their second parameter. I would expect them to behave the exact same way.
So I try forcing the type of the AbstractControlOptions object:
actions: new FormArray<ActionControl>(
  DEFAULT_STAGE_VALUES.actions.map(() => new ActionControl()),
  {nonNullable: true} as AbstractControlOptions, 
),

As I guessed, that fixed the issue. For some reason it wasn't interpreting the type correctly.
So I thought perhaps I would find out what happens if I add that type force to the FormControl controls:
actions: new FormArray<ActionControl>(
  DEFAULT_STAGE_VALUES.actions.map(() => new ActionControl()),
  {nonNullable: true} as AbstractControlOptions, 
),


Surprisingly, that yields this error:
error TS2322: Type 'FormControl<number | null>' is not assignable to type 'FormControl<number>'.
  Type 'number | null' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'.

          stageVolume: new FormControl(
          ~~~~~~~~~~~

Furthermore, if I declare a nonNullable object and pass it in to FormControl as a variable, I get the same error as I got when there was no nonNullable option at all:
const nonNullableOptions: AbstractControlOptions = {nonNullable: true};
...

stageVolume: new FormControl(
  DEFAULT_STAGE_VALUES.stageVolume,
  nonNullableOptions,
),

error TS2322: Type 'FormControl<number | null>' is not assignable to type 'FormControl<number>'.
  Type 'number | null' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'.

          stageVolume: new FormControl(
          ~~~~~~~~~~~

So my questions are:

Why do the FormArray options require an as AbstractControlOptions to work, while the same type assertion in FormControl breaks it?
Why does copying and pasting the form control options into an object break FormControl and make it think the object can go null again?

